# How to get position of a word characters in a string based on an array of words in this string

Tags: javascript, search

There is a long text, in which there are lots of types of white spaces. In order to get an array of words out of it I do
    var words   = whole_text.split(/\s+/);

Now I want to get the text after words[124], including all the original white spaces. How would I do that? The reason I do this is to get a character position in my text after a click on the character. Would be happy to hear alternative approaches as well.

Comment: Is there any chance of the input text *starting* with whitespace?

Comment: No. The text always starts with a letter.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by `get a character position in my text after a click on the character`

Comment: Click on the letter -> get the position of the letter relative to the text.

Comment: I meant how are you registering clicks? What is the DOM like? Is it a single `<p>` tag with all the text? Is every word in a `<span>`? You seem to be able to find the `chosen word` which implies you are able to distinguish between clicks on different words. A broader picture will help us give you a better solution.

Comment: It is basically a book. Every word in a <span>. Every paragraph is in <p>. All the headlines are also in <p>. Basically only spans and ps.

Comment: I posted an answer that should be able to solve the underlying task. Not sure if it's more efficient than regexing the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

From the word index you want, one option would be to use a regular expression that repeats that number of repetitions of `\S+\s`, which will match up to the word index you're interested in. For example:

```js
const str = 'foo     bar baz buzz foooo barrr bazzz   buzzzz';
const words = str.split(/\s+/);

console.log(words[2]);
// to get the text after the word at [2]:
const re = new RegExp(String.raw`(?:\S+\s+){3}`);
const textAfterWords2 = str.replace(re, '');
console.log('text after ' + words[2] + ' is:');
console.log(textAfterWords2);

console.log(words[5]);
// to get the text after the word at [5]:
const re2 = new RegExp(String.raw`(?:\S+\s+){6}`);
const textAfterWords5 = str.replace(re2, '');
console.log('text after ' + words[5] + ' is:');
console.log(textAfterWords5);

// to get just the index in the original string:
const indexOfBarrrEnd = str.match(re2)[0].length;
console.log(indexOfBarrrEnd , str.slice(indexOfBarrrEnd ));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the position of the word you can use `findIndex`:

```
let words = whole_text.trim().split(/\s+/);
let position = words.findIndex(word => word === chosenWord);
```

I used trim to cut extra white space.

And then you `slice` the original text:

```
console.log(whole_text.slice(position));
```

Comment: This will fail if the string has the selected word twice. For example if the second instance of 'bar' was clicked in the string `bar foo bar foofoo`, then your script will return `foo bar foofoo`, which does not work as intended.

Comment: @ManavM Yes, you are absolutely right! The best way I could think of right now is if the words are displayed in separate `<div>`s or `<span>`s, their indexes can also be attached to the elements as an attribute. And when clicked we can get the right index.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this works, also handles repeats:

```js
var text="hello  world hello           world lorem ipsum";
var words=text.split(/\s+/);
for(var i=0;i<words.length;i++)
  console.log(i,"*"+text.match(words.slice(0,i).join("\\s+")+"(.*)")[1]+"*");
```

Personally I would not force regexps on this task though.

Answer (score 0):

Well let's assume that the parent that holds all the words has the id `parent`. Then you can do something like

```
const parent = document.querySelector("#parent");
parent.addEventListener("click", handleClick, false);

const handleClick = (e) => {
    if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
        // target is the element that triggered the event currentTarget is the element that the event listener is attached to.
        const i = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(parent.childNodes, e.target);
        console.log(i);
    }
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

This should give you which word is clicked. If you now want to find out which character was clicked in this word, you can follow the answer in [Determine the position index of a character within an HTML element when clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8105824/determine-the-position-index-of-a-character-within-an-html-element-when-clicked)